# C++ Number guessing game - looping wall of text from if-statements

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop, control-flow

Very new to C++ and this is an assignment for school. I'm supposed to make a guessing game, displaying the following messages:

> You are too cold on lower side (display -----)
>
> You are hot on lower side (display ---)
>
> You are hot on the upper side (display +++)
>
> You are too cold on the upper sire (display +++++)
>
> YOU ARE THERE (######YOU WON ####)

I keep getting a wall of "+++++++++..." or "------..." after I input my guess, and I can't figure out why. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, guess;
    bool correct = false;

    srand((int)time(0));

    //generating random number 1-100
    num = rand()%100+1;
    cout<<num;

    cout<<"Let's play a game! I'll think of a number and you can try to guess it."<<endl;
    cout<<"Let's begin! I'm thinking of a number 1-100. What's my number?"<<endl;
    cin>>guess;

    while(correct==false)
    {
        if(guess<num)
        {
            cout<<"---";
        }
        if (guess<(num/2))
        {
            cout<<"-----";
        }

        if(guess>num)
        {
            cout<<"+++";
        }

        if (guess>(num+num/2))
        {
            cout<<"+++++";
        }

        if(guess==num)
        {
          cout<<"########YOU WON!########";
          correct=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could try reading the user's next guess inside the loop?

Comment: @DrC that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of all of your details needed to implement this guessing game but heres what I can say.  You are getting an infinite loop when you don't guess the correct answer on the first try.  This is because your `while` loop condition is based on a boolean that only gets assigned to inside the condition for guessing the correct answer (your final `if` statement in `while` loop).

Second, your if statements can print multiple strings per iteration. For example, if a user guesses `10` and the random number is `80`, the first two if statements would be true and they would each be printed since `10 < 80` is true and `10 < 80/2 //ie 40` is true as well.  Consider nesting your if statements per condition.

With that being said, here is an implementation I ran.  Go through this code and understand it.  I added a prompt for the user in the while loop so the user can keep guessing the number until correct. Hope this helps.

**NOTE**: *I did not run deep tests on this code as it is your duty to understand and debug the code as needed since it is an assignment.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num, guess;
srand((int)time(0));

//generating random number 1-100
num = rand()%100+1;
cout<<num<<endl;

cout<<"Let's play a game! I'll think of a number and you can try to guess it."<<endl;
cout<<"Let's begin! I'm thinking of a number 1-100. What's my number?"<<endl;
cin>>guess;

while(guess != num)
{
    if(guess<num)
    {
        if (guess <(num/2)) 
        {
            cout<<"-----"<< endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"---"<< endl;
        }
    }

    if(guess>num)
    {
        if (guess>(num+num/2))
        {
            cout<<"+++++"<< endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"+++"<< endl;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Guess again" << endl;
    cin >> guess;
}
cout<<"########YOU WON!########";
}
```